# Workstation Specification Check

Tags: hardware, intel, specifications

I'm unsure if this is allowed, so please tell me if it is not.

I am building a workstation for MPI/CUDA CFD work, however I am unfamiliar with server-type hardware. I have provided my current spec in the image below:

[image: Workstation Specs]

I was looking for clarification on whether the listed components are compatible with each other or whether I have overlooked something. In particular:

1. Are the CPUs compatible with the Motherboard?
2. Will the CPU Coolers fit the Motherboard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this isn't really what we do but it's an easy one so let's go for it!

> Are the CPUs compatible with the Motherboard?

Yes.

> Will the CPU Coolers fit the Motherboard?

Yes, they'll fit the CPUs but whether you have any clearance issues with anything else above them in the case I can't say.

To be honest most people would buy a pre-built server for this kind of thing - Dell aren't horribly expensive and you'd have some support - self-build is generally frowned-upon for most professional scenarios (yes and I know Amazon and Google do it but they have hundreds of staff to support them) - it might be worth you getting a quote for those.

Also of note, consider NVidia GTX 1080's instead of the 980Ti's (I have two in my gaming rig!) as they're more powerful yet use less power and run cooler.

Out of interest this isn't for software by 6Sigma is it? If so I use a very similar server for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My main concern was there is not much information online about whether FCLGA-2011-3 is the same as LGA-2011-3.

It's through a University Supplier, so we pick the parts and they build it for us to ensure we get a warranty. I just wanted to double check the components were feasible before getting a quote to avoid delay.

I considered the titan at first for its impressive FP64 ratio, however the supplier did not stock them. I'm unsure on the FP64 ratio of the 1080, any idea?

EDIT: No, not for 6Sigma, just a range of MPI and CUDA accelerated CFD applications.

Comment: Ah - good point, not entirely sure the 1080's as good at FP64 as the 980Ti